# Java sql delete row

Tags: java, sql, database, sql-delete

Hello I am trying to delete a row from my database. I am getting no errors but it is doing nothing, any help or advice would be great!

```java
public static void DeleteRow(String name) {
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = " + name + ";");
        st.executeUpdate();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess name is a varchar type in DB so do like this

```java
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = '" + name + "';");
```

enclose name within single quotes `'`

Also this is not the way you are using is not the proper way of using Preparedstatement

Us the following way:

```java
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = ?");
st.setString(1,name);
st.executeUpdate(); 

// your full code after Proper PreparedStatement

public static void DeleteRow(String name) {
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = ?");
        st.setString(1,name);
        st.executeUpdate(); 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown no need to escape single quotes

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table WHERE name = 'UserTest''

Comment: @user3268379 what is your table name? Table is a reserved keyword in mysql

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown yes thats why I mentioned that this is not the proper way of preparedstament and also I have suggested how to do

Answer (score 2):

You should never create a SQL statement in Java with String concatenation, it will be vulnerable to sql injection. Please do it this way.

```
String selectSQL = "DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = ?";
connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "MANASH_APPN","MANASH");
          PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from EMP21 where empid = ?");
           ps.setInt(1,90);
           ps.executeUpdate();
          con.commit();
          System.out.println("Records Delete Successfully....");
         con.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every open connection must be closed, or it won't get implemented and no errors will be displayed. First learned lesson.

```java
public static void DeleteRow(String name) {
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = " + name + ";");
        st.executeUpdate(); 
        connection.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQl injection. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Answer (score 0):

try this bro. use Statement

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
String SQL = "DELETE FROM Table WHERE name = '"+name+"'";
stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

Answer (score -1):

this will work
String del="DELETE FROM table WHERE name =('" + name + "')";

:)